# Stripe API call is producing multiple subscriptions when using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous, stripe-payments

I am implementing the stripe api in my node application. The problem i am having is that if i click the submit button very fast multiple times, the api is called multiple times and the stripe customer suddenly has multiple subscriptions and charges.

The scenario is when a user has a stripe customer account without a subscription since they have previously unsubscribed. Now they would like to resubscribe with a new plan since the old one is deleted.

The logic of my code is as follows:

```
1. Submit form
2. I retrieve the user from my mongo db
3. I retrieve the customer from stripe using a stored customer id (api call)
4. I create a customer subscription (api call)
5. I update the stripe customer object with their credit card (api call)
6. Respond back to user
```

- All of the above is done using **async waterfall**, each subsequent asynchronous call is in a separate function

**What I want:**

- Between steps 3 and 4 i want to retrieve the customer and check if he or she is already subscribed and prevent 4 and 5 from occurring if the user already has an active subscription.

**The Issue:**

- I am testing the scenario where the user clicks the submit button multiple times and ends up being charged for several subscriptions. I believe that it has to do with how node sends several requests at once due to its asynchronous nature and me wanting to check make an api call to check if something is set takes too long and node doesn't wait when it sends all of the requests.

How do i go about solving this.

Note: Of course i have the front end handling this to prevent user from submitting the form multiple times but this is not ideal and don't want this to be my only line of defense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**use a powerful rate limiter library**

https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter

```
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;

// Allow 1 requests per minute
var limiterPayments = new RateLimiter(1, 'minute');

exports.payWithStripe = function(req,res){
    limiterPayments.removeTokens(1,function(err,remainingRequests){
    if (err){
        return res.sendStatus(429);
    } else {
        // continue with stripe payment
    }
}
```

This will throttle per session (per user browser)

Comment: I gave it a try and it seems to hold up every user and not just that one. My app is stateless so there aren't any sessions. I use JSON Web Token for auth to prevent the need of sessions.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. A per user limiter would be similiar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-rate-limiter where the key would be the req.connection.remoteAddress

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a cache (in Redis or similar) of recent transactions, indexed by a hash derived from key transaction values (e.g. customer id, date, time, amount.)

Before submitting the subscription request to stripe, compare the current transaction to the cache. If you get a hit, you can either show an error, automatically ignore the transaction, or let the user choose whether to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button in your frontend using javascript as soon as it's clicked the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has built in functionality to help you prevent this. https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests

You need to generate a unique string and send it along with the stripe request.

Putting it in the HTML in a hidden form, a la your CORS token, then reading it out and putting it in the Stripe call will prevent double click / retries.